# Error with latest Chrome v74 and selenium-chromedriver Host header or origin header is specified and is not localhost

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running protractor 6.0.0 with selenium standalone 4.0.0 and chromedriver 74. Everything fell apart when I downloaded the latest update of Chrome (v74), released 2 days ago. Now whenever I try to run my tests, I get the following error:

```
Error: WebDriverError: Host header or origin header is specified and is not localhost.
```

Where does this come from? I am running everything on localhost.

Here are the files being downloaded when starting protractor:

```
curl -o /Users/biberli/.nvm/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/downloads/chromedriver.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
curl -o /Users/biberli/.nvm/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/downloads/selenium-server.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
curl -o /Users/biberli/.nvm/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/downloads/chromedriver_mac64.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/chromedriver_mac64.zip
curl -o /Users/biberli/.nvm/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/downloads/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/4.0/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar
```

And the full stack error I get

```
[14:27:12] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[14:27:15] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.190.111.145:4444/wd/hub
[14:27:19] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Host header or origin header is specified and is not localhost.
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/biberli/.nvm/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:559:11)
    at Executor.execute (/Users/biberli/.nvm/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[14:27:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figured this one out: you can use the "loopback" option for selenium standalone. In `protractor.conf`, use:

```
exports.config = {
    (...)
    localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
        loopback: true
    }
}
```

Edit: for those not using protractor, [here is a link to the relevant option in selenium-webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js#L56).